# Gnome extensions not working after upgrading to gnome-shell 44.2

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

After upgrading to gnome-shell 44.2, none of the extensions are working.
When I open gnome-extensions-app, it shows:[image: gnome-extensions-app screenshot]
I am unable to enable any of the extensions.

If I browse to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, it lets me flip the toggles for enabling individual extensions, but the extensions don't actually start running.